# Cannot re-set DatabaseInitializer in EF6 with existing DBConfiguration

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a DBConfiguration with a constructor having only one line:

```
SetDatabaseInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<SchedulingReadContext, Configuration>());
```

For testing I am trying to use a different initializer by doing the following in SetUp

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateAndMigrateDatabaseInitializer<SchedulingReadContext, Configuration>());
using (var context = new SchedulingReadContext())
{
   context.Database.Initialize(true);
}
```

However while debugging if I step into Database.SetInitializer, I end up in the DBContext constructor, so my DatabaseInitializer does not change.

Any solution would be helpful, Thanks

Comment: Forgot to mention that if the SetDatabaseInitializer is commented off in DBConfiguration constructor, then SetInitializer works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the Database Initializer conditionally so you're only calling `Database.SetInitializer` once.

I usually use an appSetting in my web.config which denotes what environment the application is running in as follows:

```
<add key="EnvironmentIn" value="development"/> // change this to whatever environment you are working in
```

Then in the constructor of your DbConfiguration check this setting and set the initializer accordingly:

```
     if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EnvironmentIn"] == "development")
         {
                    SetDatabaseInitializer(new DropCreateAndMigrateDatabaseInitializer<SchedulingReadContext>());
         }
     else
         {
                   SetDatabaseInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<SchedulingReadContext, Configuration>());
         }
```

Comment: So, the main thing is that one cannot call the initializer twice. I think your advice will solve the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @alexW that's correct. Although you can use the same initialization strategy for multiple contexts, you can only use one strategy per context as the the behaviour of each strategy contradicts the behaviour of others. For example, think about how DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges and DropCreateDatabaseAlways would be used together. If we